# How to Overide Admin Welcome page UI Strapi V4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system, strapi

[image]

I have read the [Documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/admin-customization.html#customization-options). but can not find a solution

Answer (score 0):

you can change the content by configure translations, update the file src/admin/app.tsx or src/admin/app.js or create new one if the file is not exists, and put this content inside the config object to be like this:

```
export default {
  config: {
    head: {
      favicon: favicon
    },
    tutorials: false,
    locales: [
      // 'en'
    ],
    translations: {
      en: {
        // add this line
        "app.components.HomePage.welcomeBlock.content.again": "Welcome to your Dashboard!"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same, could not change the UI but can able to change some text content. For me its Login page

the approach is search your whole project with the content text you want to change, but make sure its not breaking anything
so for me I had to change login page texts

this was the title key I found Auth.form.welcome.title and have replaced

goto app.js

> src/admin/app.js

```
const config = {
  translations: {
    en: {
      'Auth.form.welcome.title': 'Welcome to Dining App',
    },
  },
};

const bootstrap = app => {
  console.log('bootstrap', app);
};

export default {
  config,
  bootstrap,
};
```

** You can also translate to other locale as well